# angular 4 less files built but not included

Tags: angular, typescript, less

I started an angular 4 project and configured it with less instead of css:

```
npm install less --save
```

less files are declared in 
`.angular-cli.json`, as:

```
"styles": [
        "my-style.less",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

And in components like that:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'step-web',
  templateUrl: './web.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./web.component.less']
})
```

web.component.less contains a link to an image. 
If the path is false `ng build`  or `ng serve` do raise some errors,

but in the browser, the style is never processed: 
(and I could'nt find corresponding source in developper's sourve view)

Using developements tools, I can see the target nodes 
but it is not processed by the less instructions:

The code can be cloned from [github](https://github.com/benoitrolland/SampleNG4ImpressJsIntegration) 
(commit 054d46231df06300245680726f2bd56f4ff203b0)

(for example the background image is not inserted:

DOM node from developper tools:

```
<step-web _ngcontent-c1="" _nghost-c5=""><div _ngcontent-c5="" class="step active present" data-rotate="90" data-scale="2" data-x="1500" data-y="2300" id="abe" style="position: absolute; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate3d(1500px, 2300px, 0px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(90deg) scale(2); transform-style: preserve-3d;">
...
    <q><a>some</a></q>
...
    <div _ngcontent-c5="" class="abe"></div>
</div>
</step-web>
```

web.component.less:

```
step-web {
    #abe {
        text-align: center;
        .abe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 350px;
            background-image: url("~assets/img/abe.png");
            background-position: bottom center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 583px;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in the following way:
You have to declare your image URL in your `my-style.less` file

in your my-stlye.less file:

```
// Images
$url_cart_white: url(/assets/cart_white.png);
$url_banner_img: url(/assets/banner.jpg)
```

web.component.less file:

```
step-web {
    #abe {
        text-align: center;
        .abe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 350px;
            background: $url_cart_white;
            background-position: bottom center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 583px;
        }
    }
}
```

The above method is just a way of trying. Eventually instead of `background-image` try `background`.